# What to do with this brick work in bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, brick, tiling

We are having our bathrooms completely torn down. The tiles have been removed from all the walls. It appears they were on green plasterboard.

[image]

After the plasterboard was torn down the brickwork is exposed and looks like this.

[image]

Should all these gaps in the brickwork be filled in before any new material (I'm assuming it'll be the same type green plasterboard) is then attached? What type of material should be used to fill the gaps? Would something like Selleys No More Gaps do the job? This wall is part of one that adjoins the house next door.

I live in a country where shortcuts are taken at every single corner if it saves one minute and a little bit or work, and there's zero health and safety to anything, so I want to make sure that the correct steps are taken. Unfortunately my knowledge on such matters is somewhat limited.

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you plan to install thermal insulation?

Comment: We hadn't considered it if I'm honest. It wasn't there originally. There's one wall that adjoins the neighours house (the one with the exposed brick from the picture). The left-hand wall adjoins another bathroom and right hand wall and entrace adjoins the master bedroom. Any tips on insulation for the bathroom would be welcome. I can then follow up with the guys doing the work. Thanks!

Comment: OK, if there is heated space on the other side of the walls (another house, another room) then no insulation is needed

Answer (score 1):

Those brick joints don't have to be perfect, as long as they provide a stable support for the other wall coverings.

That green board was likely a waterproof board specifically designed to support tiles.

If you are planning on tiles then it is a shame you removed it if you are keeping the same layout. So fit new waterproof board to support your design an retile or whatever as needed.

Answer (score 1):

that brick would offer great support for a new tile wall and it does not need to be filled in; though you could use a silicone "waterproof" caulking or even a waterproof grout to fill in the gaps if you feel like it is necessary, it would not hurt it to completely seal it but you should not have any issues with it not sealed. I have years of experience with remodeling bathrooms and I would just leave it how it is, so long as the person installing the new shower makes sure that everything is sealed with a membrane-style sealer before putting up the new shower tiles or whatever you're planning to have it replaced with. I used https://diamontile.com/product/redgard-waterproofing-crack-prevention-membrane-3-5-gallon/ in most bathrooms I worked in before installing the shower pan and tile.

Comment: I would inspect the mortar.  If it just looks like incomplete coverage, it's probably fine to leave it as is.  If it exhibits any kind of deterioration, like loose pieces or gaps to outside, I'd recommend "pointing" it before you seal it back up.

Comment: The gap filler doesn't need to be waterproof - it's the layer on top which has to be waterproof.

Comment: The other reason to fill the gaps is (depending on construction) to prevent air leaks - and the resulting heat losses and lack of sound proofing.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice!

Answer (score 0):

At my location we usually apply the following:

- Coarse plaster
- Fine plaster
- Sealing slurry
- Tile adhesive
- Tiles
- Tile grout

It is beyond me if we are totally overdoing it, because that's the way the book says, or if those steps are necessary for longterm stability. Since you didn't mentioned problems with the green plasterboard (you had any water leaks?), it seems that is was fine..

Anyway, should you decide to make it somehow better: You need the materials (those specialized building materials are only available where they are up to code) and the craftsman who are trained to use them the right way..